# Problem loading Pytourch 3.0 model unexpected key "module.features.0.weight" in state_dict

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, onnx

I am trying to load a model I have trained using Pytorch,
but I keep getting the following error:

> File "convert.py", line 12, in 
>       model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model/model_vgg2d_2.pth'))   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
>   line 490, in load_state_dict
>       .format(name)) KeyError: 'unexpected key "module.features.0.weight" in state_dict'

Below is my code:

```
import torch.onnx
import torch.nn as nn

class TempModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TempModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 5, (3, 3))
    def forward(self, inp):
        return self.conv1(inp)

model = nn.DataParallel(TempModel())
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model/model_vgg2d_2.pth'))
dummy_input = Variable(torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224))
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "model_onnx/model_vgg2d_0.onnx")
```

I am working on the same machine that I have used to train the model(which has multiple GPUs).
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it possible you are trying to load a state_dict of a completely different model?? Are you trying ot force VGG weights on `TempModel`??

Comment: Ohh, That was the issue, I need to generate the exact same model for it to load,thanks! (I was used to TF where i just loaded a pb file regardless of his base model)

Answer (score 0):

When loading `state_dict` you need it to be a `state_dict` of the **same** model: you cannot load a `state_dict` of a VGG model into a completely different `BasicModel`.

---

**old answer**
You saved the model without `nn.DataParallel` applied to the model and now you are trying to load after adding this. Try

```
model = TempModel()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model/model_vgg2d_2.pth'))
model = nn.DataParallel(model)  # parallel AFTER load
```

Comment: same result - first it gave me the obvious "NameError: name 'model' is not defined",
when i did:
 model = TempModel()
 model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model/model_vgg2d_2.pth'))
 model = nn.DataParallel(TempModel())
it never got to the third row as it just gave me the same error of: 
KeyError: 'unexpected key "module.features.0.weight" in state_dict